# What is the meaning of this -> symbol in Java?

Tags: java

I am not able to understand how to make this code should work in Java7

```
RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy()
  .retryWhen((ClientResponse response) -> response.getStatus() != 200)
  .withDelay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .withMaxRetries(3);

Recurrent.get(() -> webResource.post(ClientResponse.class, input), retryPolicy);
```

What exactly this `->` symbol mean in java?

If Java7 not support it how to change it so it should work.

Comment: Switch to using Java 8, as v7 is no longer supported.

Comment: This is called as arrow `->` used in lambda expression like parameters, the `->` arrow, and an expression

Comment: @tom thx. typo mistake, corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `->` is used to denote [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), which where introduced in Java 8, thus, it will not compile against Java 7.

Taken from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-whats-new-2157071.html):

> Lambda Expressions, a new language feature, has been introduced in
>   this release. They enable you to treat functionality as a method
>   argument, or code as data. Lambda expressions let you express
>   instances of single-method interfaces (referred to as functional
>   interfaces) more compactly.

To compile (against previous versions of Java 8), you would need to rewrite the code. Otherwise you would need to compile against Java 8.

Comment: I am using one API https://github.com/jhalterman/recurrent/#retry-policies Where they used code like this it mean it will support by Java7?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi No it is supported only java 8.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi: That code is not part of Java 7. Lambda expressions where introduced in Java 8 and require Java 8 or over to compile.